# Counting occurrences whilst ignoring some occurrences in python

Tags: python, regex, search, python-2.7, count

I'm looking for a bit of help for an issue what I'm sure has a simple soultion, currently I have the following data stored in the variable: "`listing_read`" by opening the file and reading.

```
Test NA
Name: Jimmy
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla

Test BTS NA
Name: Jimmy
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla

Test NA
Name: Jimmy
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
More Data: blabla
```

I've also got the variable "`name_owner`" defined somewhere else in my script, I am wanting to do a count in the data above for the username "Jimmy" but ignoring any what have the title containing "BTS"

I was using `n_counter = listing_read.count(name_owner)` but that doesn't stop me from couting the ones with a title of BTS

Comment: Parse the file into a data structure and then work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> name_owner = 'Jimmy'
>>> r = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z\s]+\nName: {}'.format(name_owner))
>>> len([m for m in r.finditer(listing_read) if 'BTS' not in m.group(0)])
2
```

Comment: Any chance of explaining how this answer works? (still learning)